# Challenge in calling dependency service from Xamarin

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm working on accessing REST Api from Xamarin forms. I have created an interface in portable class like this by adding

```
    public interface IRestService<T>
    {
        void Post(T item, string resourceURL);
    }

    public interface IRepository
    {

    }
```

and in Drod Project I'm implemented the interface like this.

```
[assembly:Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(RestOperationsDroid))]
namespace VLog.Droid.DependencyServices
{
    public class RestOperationsDroid : IRestService<IRepository>
    {
        private const string BaseURL = "http://127.0.0.1/logger/v1/";
        HttpClient client;

        public RestOperationsDroid()
        {
            client = new HttpClient();
            client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
        }

        public async void Post(object item, string url)
        {
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format(BaseURL + url));
            var jsoncontent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            response = await client.PostAsync(uri, jsoncontent);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //Debug(@"             TodoItem successfully saved.");
            }
            else
            {
                //throw new Exception("Failed to Post data");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Calling in Xamarin.Forms (PCL project)

```
DependencyService.Get<IRestService<Log>>().Post(_logitem, "sync");
```

I'm getting an error says :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What went wrong in this implementation ?

Comment: What is the relationship between `IRepository` and `Log`?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to resolve an `IRestService<Log>` from the `DependencyService`, while your class implements `IRestService<IRepository>`. These are different types. You should implement a class that implements the specific type you want for `IRestService<T>`.

Comment: @NaveenBathina I have changed my answer. It is practically for the same reason.